# Pass tuple to function

Tags: python

I have written a function which calculates a checksum.

```
Data = ( 0x07, 0x3F, 0x20, 0xCF, 0x44, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x7B, 0x04, 0x77)

hexOrg = 0
hexData = Data
Header = (hexOrg&0xFF00>>16, hexOrg&0xFF, len(hexData))

def bcc(data):
    BCC = 0
    print(data)
    for d in data:
        print(d)
        BCC ^= d
        overflow = (BCC & 0x80) >> 7
        BCC <<= 1
        BCC &= 0xFF
        BCC |= overflow
        BCC &= 0xFF
        return BCC
```

If I pass in a tuple `Header` it works.

```
BCC = bcc(Header)
print("BCC = %02X" %  BCC)
```

I try to pass in the values which make up the tuple (either as a tuple or list) it only uses the first element.

```
print("BCC = %02X" %  bcc([hexOrg&0xFF00>>16, hexOrg&0xFF, len(hexData)]))
print("BCC = %02X" %  bcc((hexOrg&0xFF00>>16, hexOrg&0xFF, len(hexData))))
```

How can I do this without assigning the values to a variable?

I have read the answers to similar questions, but none seem applicable to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only uses the first element because of the `return` statement in the end of your loop iteration, which exits the function after processing first element of the tuple passed in to it.

Try moving the `return` statement out of the for loop. Then all 3 of your ways of calling `bcc` function should work identically.

Comment: Head slap! I don't know where the extra indentation came from - this happened when modifying code to return value rather than using global.